# Docker compose for NodeJs with MySQL on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Nodejs app that is hosted on AWS EB Single container Docker. For now I am deploying it from AWS console by uploading zip file. Everything is working as expected.
I would like to be able to push changes to AWS using CLI. So far deployment works until MySQL connection is attempted. At that point it fails with error:

> {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"fatal":true}

I am pretty sure the reason is that I don't have docker-compose.yml file. My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:10.16.3 

RUN mkdir /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install

COPY . /opt/app

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And .js to connect to MySQL:

```
var mysql= require('promise-mysql');
var util = require('util')
require('dotenv').config();

var pool = mysql.createPool({
   connectionLimit : process.env.DB_CONLIMIT,
   host            : process.env.DB_HOST,
   user            : process.env.DB_USER ,
   password        : process.env.DB_PASSWORD ,
   database        : process.env.DB_DATABASE,
})
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
   if (err) {
       if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
           console.error('Database connection was closed.')
       }
       if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
           console.error('Database has too many connections.')
       }
       if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
           console.error('Database connection was refused.')
       }
    }else{
       console.log('MySQL Connected!')  
   }
   if (connection) connection.release()
   return
})
pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)
module.exports = pool
```

I appreciate any guidance on how properly construct docker-compose.yml. I went thru several tutorials online but still a bit confused, besides some of them are several years old and I would like to use the current best practices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `docker-compose up` with the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    example_service:
        build: .
```

Explanation:

`example_service` is the name of the service you are starting. This name can be anything you want just don't include things like special characters.

`build: .` signifies that the Dockerfile is in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Getting an error: ERROR: In file .\.env: environment variable name 'AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID ' may not contains whitespace.

Comment: Is there whitespace on that line in the .env file?

Comment: @goryef For context, it seems like docker is pulling environment variables from a file that is malformed. If that is the case, then you should have a file (it may be hidden) called '.env' which should have a line in in that looks like `AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY`. Make sure that line doesn't have whitespace.

Comment: That was it. It's running now. Do i need to specify mysql connections anywhere in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I don't think so unless you want to start the mysql instance via docker-compose.